# Finished pods created by Kubernetes CronJob getting deleted after sometime

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-jobs

I created a CronJob by using below yaml file.

```
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: $DEPLOY_NAME
spec:
  # Run the job once a day at 8 PM
  schedule: "0 20 * * *"
  # If the previous job is not yet complete during the scheduled time, do not start the next job
  concurrencyPolicy: Forbid
  jobTemplate:
      spec:
        # The pods will be available for 3 days (259200 seconds) so that logs can be checked in case of any failures
        ttlSecondsAfterFinished: 259200
        template:
          spec:
            containers:
            - name: $DEPLOY_NAME
              image: giantswarm/tiny-tools
              imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
              resources:
                requests:
                  cpu: "0.01"
                  memory: 256Mi
                limits:
                  cpu: "0.5"
                  memory: 512Mi
              command: ["/bin/sh"]
              args: ["-c", "cd /home/tapi && sh entrypoint.sh"]
```

As mentioned in `ttlSecondsAfterFinished`, k8s keeps my job in the cluster. However, the pod created by the job (after completion) gets deleted after sometime.

As per [garbage collection policy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/garbage-collection/), my pod object should be dependent upon my job. And since job object is not garbage collected, my pod object should also remain alive. Am i missing something?

Comment: how long is some time?

Comment: Not very sure. 2-3 hours may be. This job is executed at night. And in morning, when we try to get the logs from pod, pod itself is not available. We tried scheduling job in day, at that time pod remained for atleast 2 hours.

Comment: `kubectl describe cronjob $DEPLOY_NAME` and check `Events`

Comment: Check the Kubernetes version - TTL for finished jobs by setting `.spec.ttlSecondsAfterFinished` was introduced in v1.12. If the version is v1.12+ then check if the feature gate `TTLAfterFinished` is enabled.

Comment: For me, events are coming as empty

Comment: @apisim version is 1.15. also feature gate must be enabled as my job objects remain alive for 3 days as configured.

Comment: Can you check `kubectl get jobs <job_name> -o yaml` to see if TTL is there?

Comment: @Crou ys and it is set to `ttlSecondsAfterFinished: 259200`

Answer (score 1):

The `.spec.successfulJobsHistoryLimit` and `.spec.failedJobsHistoryLimit` fields are optional.
These fields specify how many completed and failed jobs should be kept.
By default, they are set to 3 and 1 respectively.

You might need to set these fields to appropriate value

Comment: Although, when i check `kubectl get jobs`, i only see 3 jobs. But if i check ` kubectl describe cronjob abc`, failedjobhistortlimit is coming as 1. But success limit is coming as very high number as 824638391724

Comment: You need to describe the job that is completed

Comment: That also i did. But there is no events in that. Please tell me what else should i check in that. In job,. There is no success and failure limits defined.